# how to query by date in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have field date like this
type data = varchar

```
date
2019.01.01
2019.02.02
01.04.2016
```

i want to get data date >= 2019.01.01
i write query like this `select * from mydb date >= '2019.01.01`
the results are all data. i want the result just
 `2019.01.01`
 `2019.02.02`

anyone help me ?

Comment: **Never** store DATE values in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Mixing different date formats is worse than storing dates as strings.

Comment: @SalmanA: mixing different formats wouldn't even be possible with a correct database model

Answer (score 0):

If the column is stored as a date:

```
select t1.date -- use the column name (and if it is called "date", use the table name too)
from t1 -- the table name
where t1.date >= to_date('20190101','YYYYMMDD') -- Oracle dates can be funny
```

Comment: typedata is varchar

Answer (score 0):

With `case` to check the format of the date:

```
select * from mydb
where 
  case locate('.', date)
    when 3 then to_date(date,'DD.MM.YYYY')
    else to_date(date,'YYYY.MM.DD')
  end >= to_date('2019.01.01','YYYY.MM.DD')
```

This covers the case where there only exist dates in 2 formats:
`DD.MM.YYYY` and `YYYY.MM.DD`